# DAG level service level agreements in airflow

Tags: python, devops, airflow

I know that currently SLAs are implemented for tasks via a simple

`sla=datetime.timedelta(hours=1)`

inside a task instance, but I was wondering is there a way to implement a DAG level SLA in airflow, where an alert is sent if all the tasks within the dag don't finish within a given timedelta?

Best Regards,
Ali

Comment: answered by Maxime on the mailing list, shift the sla line to default_args

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-airflow-dev/201609.mbox/browser

Comment: I just add the direct link of the answer you got so that we don't have to look through the whole mail archive: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/airflow-dev/201609.mbox/%3CCAHEEp7XpRU7nGm5KBMiAOYVWRMO7W%3DtimbtrGH0SvrrkE3Ypgg%40mail.gmail.com%3E